# Node modules as constructor function

Tags: node.js, testing, module

I'm working on my first NodeJS project. I started building modules in the classical way as I read on books and over the internet.
As the project started growing I decided to split modules in small reusable pieces. That lead me to have a lot of `require` at the top of the file and sometime the risk to tackle circular dependencies. Moreover, this approach, doesn't really fits with testing because I had to require all the dependencies to make tests. I asked other developers a better way to solve this problem and most of them suggested me to use dependency injection with function constructor.

Suppose I have ModuleA and ModuleB,
ModuleC requires both ModuleA and ModuleB. Instead of requiring these modules an the top of the page I should pass them as argument in a constructor function.
e.g.

```
module.exports = function ModuleC(moduleA, moduleB) {
 //module implementation here....
 function doSomething() {}
 return {
   doSomething
 }
}
```

the problem with this approach, that at first looked good, is that in the main entry point of the application I have to require and instantiate all the module to pass.

```
const ModuleA = require("./moduleA");
const ModuleB = require("./moduleB");
const ModuleC = require("./moduleC");

const moduleA = new ModuleA();
const moduleB = new ModuleB();


const moduleC = new ModuleC(moduleA, moduleB);
moduleC.doSomething();
```

Now with only 3 modules I had to write 7 line of code to use a function of a module. If I had 20 modules to work with the main entry point of the application would be a nightmare.

I guess this is not the best approach and even with this method, testing is not easy.

So, I ask you to suggest/explain me the best way to achieve this simple task that I'm finding, maybe harder than it is, while starting exploring the NodeJS word. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code re-usability can also be achieved if you put all of your codes in a single file. Creating smaller modules is not the only solution. consider the following codes written in a file `allLogic.js`(let).

```
var allFunctions = function(){ };
var allFunctionsProto = allFunctions.prototype;

allFunctionsProto.getJSONFile = function(fileName){ 
    var that = this;    //use 'that' instead of 'this'
    //code to fetch json file
};


allFunctionsProto.calculateInterest = function(price){
    var that = this;    //use 'that' instead of 'this'
    //code to calculate interest
};

allFunctionsProto.sendResponse = function(data){
    var that = this;    //use 'that' instead of 'this'
    //code to send response
};

//similary write all of your functions here using "allFunctionsProto.<yourFunctionName>"

module.exports = new allFunctions();
```

---

Whenever I need to get any JSON file I know that the logic to get JSON file has already been written in `allLogic.js` file, hence I will require this module and use that as below.

```
var allLogic = require('../path-to-allLogic/allLogic.js');
allLogic.getJSON();
```

this approach is far better than creating tons of module for each work. Of course if the module gets longer you can create new module but in that case you need to consider **separation of concern** otherwise the circular dependency will haunt you.

As you are using you `moduleA` and `moduleB` in `moduleC`, if you put all of the codes from moduleA, moduleB and moduleC in a single module as I have pointed out you can reference the functions and all of the separate functions inside that module using `that` and those are also available after require.